# Git is made to work niether with giant nor with lots of tiny files. If so, what are alternatives?

Tags: git, version-control

The problems is this:
I want to version-control a dictionary (real language dictionary).
I have 2 main ways to manage this with .git:

1. Commit one gigantic 5GB .txt file to .git.
2. Break the dict into tiny .txt files, where each file contains only one dict-article and weigths somewhere between 0kb and 1kb.

As far as my expirements shown neither strategy is applicable to .git

1. In the first case, each change to the big file causes me to commit whole 5GB (and this is for any change!). Well, yeah, you can "compress" after each commit (thus making a delta file), but it takes time...
2. In the second case, commits are cheap indeed, but, the size of .git folder triples (or somewhere close to tripling, sorry, I forgot the exact factor).

As far as I know the multiplication of the .git folder is due to the fact that for each file .git must:

- Hash the file, but since original was tiny any hashing will make it's size grow
- create a link to the file (basicly another file with a hash)
- someother things (can you remind me what other reason for multiplication of the size of .git folder?

So the question is this:
Is there an alternative to .git but which is made to work with many small files?

Comment: The .git folder will also be compressed when pack files are created, is 15gb a real concern? (~tripling 5gb) How many files is "lots"?

Comment: One file per letter could be a nice compromise. Ie A,B,C...

Comment: Why not keep your big file and use https://git-lfs.github.com/ which is made for that?

Comment: How many small files did you have? I tried it with ~50,000 files. it has produced  2.7G data struct for 5G of the summary data.

Comment: I had 500 000 for a small dictionary. :) I need 100 of such dictionaries.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Some dicts can't be splitted in such a manner. There are non-alphabet languages.

Comment: @Philippe consider 10 000 commits in a day for such a dictionary. Would you still recommend LFS? I just don't see how it helps...

Comment: Which VCS is capable to support such numbers? Which one do you use at the moment? Perhaps [VFS for Git](https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit) could help... But I can't stop thinking that probably you're doing something wrong... with 10000 commits/day. Is keeping the history make sense with such a use?

Comment: Which is capable? Well any SQL DB will do the job, but I don't want end user to have the need to install anything external even sqlite. I'll read about VFS, thanks. Keeping history is needed, since a human contribution validation needed for those commits.

Comment: @coobit for 500,000 files it initially generated a 4G git core. `git repack` brought it down to 2.7G. So, having a lot of small files is very efficient with git. Large files are not as efficient and you should use lfs for those.